# introductory google maps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

hi i wanted to display a us state on google map with borders drawn,

when the user opens up a page i wanted to show in the center that state...with borders drawn.

additionally i wanted to put a button on that page so that user clicks it and draws a rectangle on the state, the system will just have to popup the latitude and longitude of the selected area, and area ...

can you anyone guide me through the steps? or is there any good reference that i could follow. thanks in advance!

as an example of what i mean 
http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/gridsphere/gridsphere?gs_action=lidarNSAF&cid=geonlidarframeportlet

Comment: You'll need to get your shift key fixed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start in the Google AJAX APIs playground, here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple

There are tons of samples here and by playing with them you should get an idea of how to do what you want and/or come up with some more specific questions.